# JQuery calendar to trace appointments

Tags: jquery, web-applications, calendar

I'm implementing a simple web application to keep track of dates for job interviews within the company.

There is an inteface to insert/update date and description for the appointment, and now I'd like to create a page with a calendar showing the dates selected for appointments.
It could be useful to see details for each date clicking on it.

Can I achieve this using JQuery datepicker? or is there some other plug-in to implement this type of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my personal experience FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin that provides a full-sized, drag & drop calendar at it's best. i say this will be your best bet. it is accepted by wide variety of developers pluggable almost every web technology. it is a jquery based solution and also documented very well. It is also easily customizable (ex: like outlook calendar). I would suggest/recommend you using the FullCalendar plugin. you can have a look at demo and Documentation **[here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)** .

**Update**

to start with you can find a simple sample java integration of FullCalendar plugin **[here](https://github.com/biesior/Play-20-Sample-FullCalendar-Java)** on gitHub 
If you face any issues the on SO you will find a number of questions and issues faced by the developers like you and me.

I hope this will help you.